# List of lists (2D array) iteration and assigning values

Tags: python, list

I have this part of code that is giving me problems, I have seen people accessing list of list elements in similar way like list[sublist][element] in examples. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
fcsv = [["1", "0"]] * 6
for i in range[0, 6]:
    print(fcsv[i][0])

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/Python/Project/Main.py", line 54, in <module>
for i in range[0, 6]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Instead of brackets `[0, 6]` you must use parentheses `(0, 6)` with `range`. BTW - 0 is not needed `range(6)` will suffice

Comment: Thats right. "range" is a function not an indexable object

Comment: So obvious now :D I was loosing my mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of brackets [0, 6] you must use parentheses (0, 6) with range. There is also no need for 0, you can just write:

```
for i in range(6):
```